# files.list() returns an incomplete list when searching for q='FOLDER_ID' in parent

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to gather all of the files and folders that are descendants of a given folder.

To do this I use file.list() with `q="'FOLDER_ID' in parent" and trashed=false` with FOLDER_ID being the ID of the folder I am interested in. As I process the results I keep track of all of the folders that get returned from this request and then repeat the files.list() call using the new folders in the `q` parameter. I combine multiple folders in one request by using `or` and continue to repeat this until no new folders are returned.

Example:

Initial Request: `q="('FOLDER_ID' in parent) and trashed=false"`
All Subsequent Requests: `q="('FOLDER_ID_1' in parent or 'FOLDER_ID_2' in parent or 'FOLDER_ID_3' in parent ...) and trashed=false"`

(For more information about how to create queries see [Drive REST API - Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters))

Sometimes this returns all the folders it should and other times some are left out. This doesn't happen if I remove the `q` parameter as every single file and folder are returned, none are missing.

After some testing/trial and error, I discovered that if I am not receiving all the folders I should be, sending a request with no `q` seems to "fix" the problem. The next time I run my application and it uses `q`, all the correct folders do get returned.

Other Information:

- It is not a permissions issue, I am using `drive.readonly`
- It is not a `pageSize` issue as I have tried different values for this and get different results.
- It is not a `pageToken` issue as I make sure to send a request again with the given `nextPageToken` when it exists.
- I am running this on a folder that has a little under 4,000 descendant folders in it and a little under 25,000 descendant files in it.

I feel like this must be a bug related to using multiple folders in the `q` parameter in a single request, considering that I can perform the exact same process and will get different results seemingly randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you abandon the approach you've taken. Making so many calls to Drive will take forever and possibly give you quota problems.

It's much, much simpler to simply fetch all the folders in a single query, and then build an in-memory hierarchy of the folder ID's you're interested in. Then run a second set of queries to fetch files with those parents.

Alternatively, if these files are being created by an application, make them all children of a common dummy parent folder that you can query against.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just fetching folders first does seem like a reasonable alternative. However, I don't feel this should be necessary based on Google's documentation and guides for the Drive API and I don't think its much simpler since in both scenarios I need to build an in memory hierarchy. Also, believe it or not it doesn't take very long to complete this process, generally around 1 min with <100 drive calls.

Comment: Try it. You'll like it. Another trick would be to update each folder to make it a direct descendent of a dummy parent. Be aware that Drive does not enforce hierarchy, so your recursion should guard against a circular set of relationships.

Comment: I'll test it out. I do think the dummy folder idea sounds good. But in my situation the folders are not created by an application so that's not really feasible. I also was trying to make this a very general script that could work in any situation, so I'd rather stay away from that.

Comment: After testing your suggestion of querying for all folders and then querying for all files in the relevant folders it does not make sense for me to do. It takes the same amount of time to complete this process and it is not simpler to implement. It is certainly a viable way to go about getting all folders and files that are under a root folder but it is not better. The problem lies with Google.

Comment: @pinoyyid How would you fetch all the folders in a single query?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan simply list all files with the folder mime type. Note that you will need to loop on this until next page token is null.

Comment: @pinoyyid Ahh. Wicked. Do you think this would be the fastest way? My dilemma is users in our org have thousands of shared drives and I need to write a way for them to dump all files in a specific folder or the entire shared drive. Debating using `in parents` or just getting all folders like you say.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan in my experience, getting all folders is fastest. However this always comes down to the height and width of your folder hierarchy. There could easily be cases where "in parents" is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue when looking for all files a given user owns, eg:

```
'example.user@company.com' in owners and trashed=false
```

I have about 5000 files and usually I can iterate through all of them via pagination. Some days however (like today) I only get <100 results with the query above. When I rewrite my code to fetch files for a given parent-ID and then recursively iterate through the sub-folders, I will get all files. Afterwards the original query succeeds again as well.

It looks like some kind of caching issue on the google-drive server to me.

Comment: Interesting, so I guess like you said it is not tied to just one type of query. Definitely an issue on Google's end then.