# files().list returns incomplete and inconsistent list when using different pageSize

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a python script that attempts to list all files and folders in a given folder.
This is the python code:

```
page_token = in_json.get('pageToken', None)
res = self._drive.files().list(
        orderBy='folder, name',
        pageSize=1000,
        pageToken='page_token',
        q='(\'PARENT_ID\' in parents) and (trashed = false)',
        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, parents, name, modifiedTime, size, mimeType, md5Checksum, trashed)').execute()
```

PARENT_ID is the id of the parent folder, and page_token is set to the nextPageToken of previous response.
The folder (folder_0) I want to list contains 4096 files (0.a, 0.b, 1.a, 1.b, ..., 2047.a, 2047.b), but the return list only contains 4095 files (603.a is missing)
I change the query filter q to '(\'PARENT_ID\' in parents) **and (name = \'603.a\')** and (trashed = false)', and keep other fields unchange, the file 603.a can be list normally.
Then I use the original query filter q and change pageSize to 400/300/100, different files are missing (400: missing 1353.a, 300: no missing, 100: missing 1393.b).
(Using the same pageSize can get the same result, i.e., missing ths same file)

I try to list other folder (folder_1, folder_2, folder_3), each folder also contains 4096 files (0.a, 0.b, 1.a, 1.b, ..., 2047.a, 2047.b).
This is the result: (pageSize: missing files ('X' means no missing files))
folder_1: 100:503.a,    300:1091.a,         400: 1833.b,    1000:X
folder_2: 100:863.b,    300:194.b,          400: X,         1000:X
folder_3: 100:1085.a,   300:1896.a & 64.b,  400: X,         1000:X

I also try to upload (using files().create) and remove (using files().delete) file within that folder (folder_0) to observe the list result.
When I upload a file with similar name (603_), the missing file (603.a) shows up.
Then I remove the file I uploaded (603_) and list again, 1-st time the missing file (603.a) still exist, but from the 2-nd time the file disappeared again.
Below is the detailed steps:
(when pageSize=1000)
1.                  files().list: (4095/4096) missing 603.a
2. (upload 603_)  → files().list: (4097/4097) X
3. (remove 603_)  → files().list: (4096/4096) X
4. (do nothing)   → files().list: (4095/4096) missing 603.a
5. (upload 1393_) → files().list: (4096/4097) missing 563.a <--- another file missing

(when pageSize=100)
1.                  files().list: (4095/4096) missing 1393.b
2. (upload 603_)  → files().list: (4095/4097) missing 2 files (1393.b and  592.a) <---another file missing
3. (upload 1393_) → files().list: (4097/4098) missing 1491.b <---another file missing
4. (remove 603_)  → files().list: (4097/4097) X
5. (remove 1393_) → files().list: (4096/4096) X
6. (do nothing)   → files().list: (4095/4096) missing 1393.b

Other Information:
* It is not a pageToken issue as I make sure to send a request again with the given nextPageToken when it exists, and concatenate the response object list properly.
* This condition happens in an unlimited storage account. I use another unlimited storage account and list folders with the same structure, the result list is correct.

I have no ideas about this conditions since there is no clear pattern to find.
Thank you for taking a look into this issue!

Comment: It seems that this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168636/files-list-returns-an-incomplete-list-when-searching-for-q-folder-id-in-pare) is related to your question. Just check this one if it can give you an idea about your problem. Also I found out that this issue is already filed in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4531&q=files.list&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner). If you feel that this is a bug, file a ticket in the public issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have seen this question before asking question but I thought the situation is something different. For example, I only specify one parent folder instead of combining multiple folders in one request. I wonder if anyone suffer the same situation and how to solve it. Thank you!